# Confluence Site viewing via Android-Chrome Redirects URL to many times but Desktop Chrome and other Browsers do not

Tags: nginx, chrome, android, http-proxy

I just posted a URL and tested viewing it I noticed that in Chrome on Android it redirects too many times to the following URL. I tried clearing my cookies and browsing data but it still did the same thing. I figure it is a site setting I need to change. The site is hosted on Google Cloud, it is a Confluence site being proxied by a NGinX server running inside the same VM.

**Test Cases:**

- **Navigate to "Test URL" from Android-Chrome and get Redirected to "Bad URL" --> Why?/How To Fix?**
- Request "Desktop Site" on Android-Chrome and navigate to "Test URL" and get expected URL
- Navigate to "Test URL" via Android-Firefox and get expected URL
- Navigate to "Test URL" on Chrome/FireFox/Edge/IE (Any Browser) on Desktop PC (Win10) and get expected URL!

**Test URL:** https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/display/FREES/Prep+Linux+OS+for+GPU+Passthrough+-+Blacklist+nouveau+and+use+vfio-pci+drivers+script

**Another Test URL:**
https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/display/FREES/Free+Software+Servers

**Bad URL:** https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/#content/view/327684

Note: Another user has confirmed that this is a specific issue with Android Chrome but not with Android Firefox or desktop Chrome. Even with Android Chrome when requesting desktop version it works!

Update: Here is my NGinX configuration

```
##Confluence
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    www.freesoftwareservers.com freesoftwareservers.com;

       return         301 https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/;

}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.freesoftwareservers.com freesoftwareservers.com;

rewrite ^/wiki / permanent;

location / {

        proxy_pass              http://localhost:8091/;
        include                 /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    }
}

root@confluence:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# cat /etc/nginx/proxy.conf
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
client_max_body_size    10m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_connect_timeout   90;
proxy_send_timeout      90;
proxy_read_timeout      90;
proxy_buffers           32 4k;
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Confluence-specific issue with Android clients.

Comment: And that's not Linux related???? @JigglyNaGa What site would you say is appropriate?

Comment: Confluence support?  The server works correctly for clients that tell Confluence they want the desktop site, so it's Confluence that decides whether to redirect or not, and it's beyond the control of the system hosting it.  Although if you could show a capture of the working and looping HTTP exchanges, it may be possible to suggest a workaround.

Comment: @JigglyNaga Turns out the issue was on the `system hosting it` and was a TomCat Proxy NGinX issue.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers If you have an answer to you issue, then please consider adding it as a proper answer now. Ideally, your answer should also explain _why_ the solution resolves the issue.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks, I do try to always accept/answer questions, as you can see this was old, but I followed up! I'm not sure if you voted to close this, but do you really think it was off-topic?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers I only reopened the issue (after your flagging of it), never closed it or up/down voted on it. Web-related things are not my forte, but seeing as you actually had a solution to the issue I opted for reopening it so that you could add it as a proper answer rather than as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to the server name not matching the proxy url. While it worked somehow with Desktop apparently it didn't work with Mobile. I can confirm the issue wasn't with anything cached as I moved the website from Google Cloud to my LAN and still experienced the same issue.

Before I had my proxy using `confluence.freesoftwareservers.com` as the proxy name and it worked, but changing it to `www.freesoftwareservers.com` which is how it's accessed publicly fixed it.

Here is the working connector I got from Atlassian Support (They are awesome w/ support!)

**Update:**

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Can-t-view-site-on-Mobile-browser-Redirects-to-many-times/qaq-p/1033424

https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/display/FREES/Confluence+HTTPS+SSL+Reverse+Proxy+via+NginX

**The issue was related to the TomCat Proxy Connector** not with NGinX setup.

Edit the following file:

```
nano /opt/atlassian/confluence/conf/server.xml && service confluence restart
```

Here is a working config for Proxy via NGinX & HTTPS

```
<Server port="8000" shutdown="SHUTDOWN" debug="0">
    <Service name="Tomcat-Standalone">
        <!--
         =================================================================================$
         DEFAULT - Direct connector with no proxy, for unproxied HTTP access to Confluence.

     If using a http/https proxy, comment out this connector.
     =================================================================================$
    -->

<Connector port="8090"
       maxThreads="200"
       minSpareThreads="25"
       connectionTimeout="20000"
       enableLookups="false"
       maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
       protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
       redirectPort="8443"
       acceptCount="100"
       disableUploadTimeout="true"
       scheme="https"
       proxyName="www.freesoftwareservers.com"
       proxyPort="443"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The nginx proxy configuration seems OK.

However, Confluence has mobile specific sections / content.

You must have there http link (s) that are creating a loop with your http to https redirection in nginx.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What do you mean confluence has mobile specific content? And how would your answer explain that the issue is isolated to only Android-Chrome.

Comment: Probably client handling detection code, you can serve specific content to specific platform and browsers. I am a system guy, I do not know confluence that well..

Comment: Yeah, application /  layer 7 issues

Comment: Still, is trouble shooting Linux software off topic?

Comment: I feel like it's just a line of code somewhere that needs tweaking